# What I should to do with not subscriptable problem in python?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, xlsx

My idea is prepare an US map with information which state "born" highest number of NBA players.

[image: My excel]

and I found this tutorial https://plot.ly/python/choropleth-maps/

I tried to modify code like this:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.ExcelFile('playersnba.xlsx')

data = [ dict(
type = 'choropleth',
locations = df['State'],
z = df['Numbers'],
text = df['State'],
colorscale = [[0,"rgb(5, 10, 172)"],[0.35,"rgb(40, 60, 190)"],[0.5,"rgb(70, 100, 245)"],\
    [0.6,"rgb(90, 120, 245)"],[0.7,"rgb(106, 137, 247)"],[1,"rgb(220, 220, 220)"]],
autocolorscale = False,
reversescale = True,
marker = dict(
    line = dict (
        color = 'rgb(180,180,180)',
        width = 0.5
    ) ),
colorbar = dict(
    autotick = False,
    tickprefix = '#',
    title = 'players'),
 ) ]
```

My problem is:

```
...line 8, in <module>
    locations = df['State'],
TypeError: 'ExcelFile' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Hi roninuzi, welcome on SO. I hope you're going to find an answer for your question. It is a good idea to read something about [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and produce a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [mcve2](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports)

Comment: This is incomplete code and not enough to understand why you get the error. Please post a full example and explain what you want to do, not just mention the error.

Comment: The problem with your code is not in the snippet you shared with us.

Comment: What is `df`? Where does it come from?  Why do you expect it to respond to the `[]` operator, etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

It should be written this way

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.ExcelFile('playersnba.xlsx').parse()
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to read an excel file into a dataframe is to use `ExcelFile.parse()`, not just ExcelFile. So:

```
df = pd.ExcelFile.parse('playersnba.xlsx')
```